# python play again function executes first if

Tags: python

I have imported sys and created a "play again" function that is called correctly and outputs to the screen. However, the function executes `os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, *sys.argv)` no matter what input it is given.

```
def playAgain():
     print("would you like to play again? Y/N :")
     playAgainx  = input()
     if playAgainx == "Y" or "y" or "yes" or "Yes" or "YES":
          os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, *sys.argv)
     elif playAgainx == "n" or "N":
          sys.exit()
     else:
         print("invalid input")
         playAgain()
```

Comment: ```if playAgainx == "Y" or "y" or "yes" or "Yes" or "YES":``` this doesn't do what you think it does. - ```if playAgainx in ["yes, "y", "YES"]``` will do what you want.

Comment: In Python ```if playAgainx == "Y" or "y" or "yes" or "Yes" or "YES":``` will always evaluate to True because non-empty string in Python evaluates to True. To do what you intended you need to add ```playAgainx == ``` in front of all your options...So like ```playAgainx == "Y" or playAgainx == "y" or playAgainx == "yes"..etc.

Comment: Also, using the string method `lower` will reduce the number of cases to test to two.

Comment: You need to provide the statement for all of it's occurences: If playAgainx == "Y" or playAgainx == "y" ... And so on. Problem is: the boolean value of the converted "yes" is true, therefore at least one of the statements in the "if" is true and it enters it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
if playAgainx.lower() in ["y","yes"]:
```

instead of

```
if playAgainx == "Y" or "y" or "yes" or "Yes" or "YES":
```

In this way the if statement will be true in case of y or yes (indifferent of its case)